# How do I properly split comma delimited text in Delphi Syndey 10.4?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am converting code from Lazarus to Delphi 10.4 Sydney and have a line that throws an error:

```pascal
// Split line and put it into a new array, txtDataArray
txtDataArray := txtToParse.Split(['.', ',', '!'], TStringSplitOptions.ExcludeEmpty);
```

`txtToParse` is comma delimited text variable.

How would I correctly write that to work in Delphi 10.4 Sydney?

I tried this and I get an error that states:

> Incompatible Types - a Dynamic Array and System TArray<System String> at line 340:

Under `var` I have:

```pascal
// For splitting
charArray : Array[0..2] of Char;
txtToParse : String;
txtArray : array of String;
```

Then in the main function I have:

```pascal
// Split line and put it into a new array, txtArray
charArray[0] := '.';
charArray[1] := ',';
charArray[2] := '!';
txtArray := txtToParse.Split(charArray);
```

How can I get this to work in Delphi 10.4 Sydney?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change this declaration:

`txtArray : array of String;`

To this:

`txtArray : TArray<String>;`

The reason is explained in detail in the documentation:

[Type Compatibility and Identity (Delphi)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity_(Delphi))

And in particular:

[Array Types and Assignments](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Array_Types_and_Assignments)

> **Arrays are assignment-compatible only if they are of the same type**. Because the Delphi language uses name-equivalence for types, the following code will not compile.
>
> ```pascal
> var
>   Int1: array[1..10] of Integer;
>   Int2: array[1..10] of Integer;
> ...
> Int1 := Int2;
> ```
>
> To make the assignment work, declare the variables as:
>
> ```pascal
> var
>   Int1, Int2: array[1..10] of Integer;
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```pascal
> type
>   IntArray = array[1..10] of Integer;
> var
>   Int1: IntArray; Int2: IntArray;
> ```

And

[Overloads and Type Compatibility in Generics](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overloads_and_Type_Compatibility_in_Generics)

> Two non-instantiated generics are considered assignment compatible only if they are identical or are aliases to a common type.
>
> Two instantiated generics are considered assignment compatible if the base types are identical (or are aliases to a common type) and the type arguments are identical.

In FreePascal, `Split()` returns a `TStringArray` which is a plain vanilla alias for `array of string`, and so is assignment-compatible with an `array of string` variable.

But in Delphi, `Split()` returns a `TArray<String>`, which is a Generic alias for `array of T` where `T` is `string`, so it is a distinct Generic type, and thus is not assignment-compatible with an `array of String` variable, only with a `TArray<String>` variable.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you for the help and the excellent advice.  I will read all this in depth.  I have a LOT to learn going from Lazarus to Delphi 10.4.